# Log execution time of each method of the request using Spring AOP

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, spring-aop

Suppose I have a basic Spring boot application with a simple architecture (Controller, Service, Repository). I'm trying to log the execution time of each layer in the application (and different things from each layer), I'm trying to do this using Spring AOP with an @Around Aspect. The thing is that the application is a concurrent application and multiple requests can come at the same time, so if i do something like this:

```java
 @Around("controller() || restController() ")
 public Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info("time elapsed" + timeElapsed)
    //Log some other Controller useful info
 }

 @Around("service() ")
 public Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info("time elapsed" + timeElapsed)
    //Log some other Service useful info
 }

 @Around("repository() ")
 public Object logAround(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info("time elapsed" + timeElapsed)
    //Log some other Repository useful info
 }
```

I won't be able to follow the logs of each request because multiple concurrent requests can happen at a time.
I'm using SLF4J with lombok implementation, but I think I can switch to any other implementation of SLF4J such as log4j if it makes any difference for what I want.
I'd love to have a one-line log for each request.

Comment: Create `ThreadLocal` on the top-most layer (e.g. controller in your case, or better already in some servlet filter) with a unique request tracking number and log that together with the timing information of every lower level.

Answer (score 1):

To track timing for each request.

- Add Thread id as part of logging by changing log format as below
  Thread id will be unique for each request

  %d %-5level [%thread] [%logger{36}] : %msg%n%rEx
- As you are logging time performance of each layer, redirect performance logging to separate file.